# Same UI libraries for Angular and Flutter

Tags: angular, flutter, material-design, angular17

I want a library like https://m3.material.io/ this but as you know that the update will come on next angular version which will support material 3 design
Please suggest me any library like m3

I have tried searching for the libraries which are compatible with angular as well as flutter

Comment: Are you asking for Flutter or Angular?
If for Flutter, the flutter already uses material 3 design check the [flutter release notes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/whats-new).

Then The angular you can check the on it https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22738. Try using search engines carefully.